# Why reflective Members must be copied before propagation?

Tags: java, reflection, copy, jdk-internal-api

If you look into the source code of getting reflective objects of fields, methods or constructors, their copies are returned. Lets take getting field as example:

```
    /**
 * Returns an array of {@code Field} objects reflecting all the fields
 * declared by the class or interface represented by this
 * {@code Class} object. This includes public, protected, default
 * (package) access, and private fields, but excludes inherited fields.
 *
 * <p> If this {@code Class} object represents a class or interface with no
 * declared fields, then this method returns an array of length 0.
 *
 * <p> If this {@code Class} object represents an array type, a primitive
 * type, or void, then this method returns an array of length 0.
 *
 * <p> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any
 * particular order.
 *
 * @return  the array of {@code Field} objects representing all the
 *          declared fields of this class
 * @throws  SecurityException
 *          If a security manager, <i>s</i>, is present and any of the
 *          following conditions is met:
 *
 *          <ul>
 *
 *          <li> the caller's class loader is not the same as the
 *          class loader of this class and invocation of
 *          {@link SecurityManager#checkPermission
 *          s.checkPermission} method with
 *          {@code RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers")}
 *          denies access to the declared fields within this class
 *
 *          <li> the caller's class loader is not the same as or an
 *          ancestor of the class loader for the current class and
 *          invocation of {@link SecurityManager#checkPackageAccess
 *          s.checkPackageAccess()} denies access to the package
 *          of this class
 *
 *          </ul>
 *
 * @since 1.1
 * @jls 8.2 Class Members
 * @jls 8.3 Field Declarations
 */
@CallerSensitive
public Field[] getDeclaredFields() throws SecurityException {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        checkMemberAccess(sm, Member.DECLARED, Reflection.getCallerClass(), true);
    }
    return copyFields(privateGetDeclaredFields(false));
}
```

And

```
// Returns an array of "root" fields. These Field objects must NOT
// be propagated to the outside world, but must instead be copied
// via ReflectionFactory.copyField.
    private Field[] privateGetDeclaredFields(boolean publicOnly) {
    Field[] res;
    ReflectionData<T> rd = reflectionData();
    if (rd != null) {
        res = publicOnly ? rd.declaredPublicFields : rd.declaredFields;
        if (res != null) return res;
    }
    // No cached value available; request value from VM
    res = Reflection.filterFields(this, getDeclaredFields0(publicOnly));
    if (rd != null) {
        if (publicOnly) {
            rd.declaredPublicFields = res;
        } else {
            rd.declaredFields = res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

And

```
    private static Field[] copyFields(Field[] arg) {
    Field[] out = new Field[arg.length];
    ReflectionFactory fact = getReflectionFactory();
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        out[i] = fact.copyField(arg[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

And in jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory

```
    /** Makes a copy of the passed field. The returned field is a
    "child" of the passed one; see the comments in Field.java for
    details. */
public Field copyField(Field arg) {
    return langReflectAccess().copyField(arg);
}
```

And in java.lang.reflect.Field

```
    // For sharing of FieldAccessors. This branching structure is
// currently only two levels deep (i.e., one root Field and
// potentially many Field objects pointing to it.)
//
// If this branching structure would ever contain cycles, deadlocks can
// occur in annotation code.
private Field               root;
```

And in java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess (implementation of jdk

```
    public Field       copyField(Field arg) {
    return arg.copy();
}
```

And finally back to java.lang.reflect.Field

```
    /**
 * Package-private routine (exposed to java.lang.Class via
 * ReflectAccess) which returns a copy of this Field. The copy's
 * "root" field points to this Field.
 */
Field copy() {
    // This routine enables sharing of FieldAccessor objects
    // among Field objects which refer to the same underlying
    // method in the VM. (All of this contortion is only necessary
    // because of the "accessibility" bit in AccessibleObject,
    // which implicitly requires that new java.lang.reflect
    // objects be fabricated for each reflective call on Class
    // objects.)
    if (this.root != null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not copy a non-root Field");

    Field res = new Field(clazz, name, type, modifiers, slot, signature, annotations);
    res.root = this;
    // Might as well eagerly propagate this if already present
    res.fieldAccessor = fieldAccessor;
    res.overrideFieldAccessor = overrideFieldAccessor;

    return res;
}
```

But why? Cannot we just simply access the root Field object and mess with it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert with reflection, so there might be other reasons. But a Field is mutable (`setAccessible()`). Not returning a copy would mean that making it accessible in one part of the code would make it accessible everywhere, even in other code relying on the field not being accessible, or not allowed tomake it accessible.